# Seeking ML Model Recommendations for Enhancing OCR on Corrupted Text Images

Tags: python, pytorch, gan, ocr

I am working on a project where I need to perform Optical Character Recognition (OCR) on text-based images. However, these images are corrupted in various ways (e.g., blurred, distorted, low resolution), which significantly diminishes the accuracy of the OCR results.

I have already tried several preprocessing steps, such as dialation/erosion on binary image and also crimmins speckle_= removal , but the outcomes are still not satisfactory. My goal is to enhance the quality or clarity of these corrupted images before applying OCR to improve the accuracy of the text extraction.

I came across a model named OCR-VQGAN, which seems close to what I need, but it's not entirely suited to my specific use case. I am looking for recommendations on machine learning models or approaches that could assist in this scenario. Ideally, I am seeking models that have been successful in:

-Image restoration or enhancement for text-based images.
-Deblurring or denoising text in images.
-Improving the quality of images to enhance OCR accuracy.

Any guidance on existing models, research papers, or GitHub repositories that could aid in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Also, if there are any specific strategies or techniques in image processing or machine learning that you think might be beneficial, I would be very interested to hear about them.

Here is one type of image with what I am working .

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!